# RestSharp returning JSON element as object instead of array

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp, ups

I send a JSON request to an API. The response contains an `Alert` element that is defined as an array. However, if `Alert` contains only one element, RestSharp returns it as an object.

JSON response, shortened:

```json
{
   ...
   "Alert": {
       "Code": "110971",
       "Description": "Your invoice may vary from the displayed reference rates"
   },
   ...
}
```

If the same request is sent with Postman, the `Alert` element of the response is correctly returned as an array with only one element.

JSON response, shortened:

```json
{
   ...
   "Alert": [
       {
           "Code": "110971",
           "Description": "Your invoice may vary from the displayed reference rates"
       }
   ],
   ...
}
```

Is there a way to get the correct response (`Alert` as array) with RestSharp, too?

I'm using RestSharp 106.10 and .NET Framework 4.8. RestSharp 106.15 shows the same behaviour and I cannot upgrade to a newer version.

Changing the definition of the response class for deserialization is no option. If the "Alert" contains two or more elements, it is correctly returned as array.

Comment: As suggested by [ask], please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically (simplified) C# code that demonstrates the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `SingleOrArrayConverter` from [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182) in settings somewhere?

Comment: @dbc Trying to provide a MRE I found the problem, I added the request object directly as JSON body (`AddJsonBody(requestObject)`) instead of serializing it before adding: `AddJsonBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestObject))`. Thank you!

Comment: @dbc Your SingleOrArrayListConverter is very helpfull, too. It served as workaround before serializing the request and still helps at different points in the response, where the API returns an array or a single element.